# How to Log Validation Exceptions in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, exception, handler, laravel-10

I'm trying to track down a very specific issue with an external API making requests to my server. How can I make changes to my exception handler so that request validation exceptions get logged in my error log file? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try `Log::error("log text")` ? Do you have any code written?

Comment: Overwrite $internalDontReport in Handler.php and remove this exception from this prop.

Comment: I believe this to be a valid question. I don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

[custom exceptions](https://dev.to/jackmiras/laravels-exceptions-part-2-custom-exceptions-1367)

```
php artisan make:exception
```

[doc laravel errors](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors)

Log::error('Validation Error: ' . $exception->getMessage());

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers, but I was able to find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73066132/9980193

This was the method I added to Handler.php:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


 public function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {

        \Log::info([
            'errors' => $e->errors(),
            'request' => $request->all(),
        ]);

        return parent::convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Edit the `register` method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

```
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage(), $this->buildExceptionContext($e));
        }
    });
}
```

Now whenever a validation error occurs, it will be written to your log without changing how it is reported to your end user.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried this, but unfortunately this didn't work in Laravel 10.